# Need help. PC keep restarting

Tags: crash, reboot

MOBO - Rog Strix B550f Wifi Gaming

RAM - CORSAIR Vengeance RGB Pro SL 16GB

GPU - 1660 Super

CPU - Ryzen 7 3700x

PSU - CorsairRM 750

OS - Windows 10 Pro

I'm pretty exhausted so it'll be a summary of what happened.

Newly built pc. It was working for a couple days.. then it crashed when I was playing. it restarted multiple times. tried windows repair and it didn't work.. so i tried isolating the problem. i tried different gpu.. tried reseating the cables.. tried different ram. i tried reinstalling windows.. i tried almost everything.. it might be the mobo or cpu..

i checked msinfo32..

here's what i've found.. https://pastebin.com/rgYSp1qu

Comment: Your link is "pending moderation".

Comment: Is your PSU powerful enough?

Comment: I would consider double checking or replacing (returning if possible) the PSU first. It may not be delivering enough power or may have some other issue (ex. does it have any switches that affect power output?). Then it might be worth looking at the motherboard, and finally the CPU. It might be a stretch, but I wouldn't rule out a bad power connection (e.g. a loose socket or faulty power cord) or case switch issue either. Also, buying an multiple outlet block that is designed for electronics (i.e. one that smooths out any power fluctuations) might be worth considering as well.